# A sentence true in a field of characteristic 0 but false in a field of positive characteristic

Tags: logic, model-theory

I need help. My problem is the following.
I like to know if there exist a sentence true in complex a field but false in a field of positive characteristic.
Thanks

Comment: a classical is about zeroes of polynomials

Comment: @janmarqz I'm curious what you have in mind. There are fields of positive characteristic which are algebraically closed. (And algebraic closure is not expressible by a first-order sentence . . .)

Answer (score 5):

It depends exactly how you phrase the question. *(And I presume "sentence" means "first-order sentence", because of the model theory tag.)*

If you want a sentence true in every field of characteristic zero, and false in every field of positive characteristic, then this can't happen; consider the negation of such a sentence, and apply the Compactness Theorem.

If you want a sentence true in every field of characteristic zero and false in *some* field of positive characteristic, consider the sentence "$\forall x(p\cdot x=0)$" for a fixed prime $p$; this is true in exactly the fields of characteristic $p$, so its *negation* is true in every field of characteristic zero, and false in some field of positive characteristic.

Comment: @NoahShweber I think sentence true in a complex field and false in everz finite field of characteristic p>0

Comment: @joeblack Alright, well: what have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I tried something about the property of $\mathbb i$ but I do not find the solution

Comment: @NoahSchweber Algebra police here: $\forall x\, x^p = 1$ is not true in any field ($0^p = 0$). I think you meant $\forall x\, x^p = x$, which is true only in $\mathbb{F}_p$ (a polynomial of degree $p$ has at most $p$ roots). For a sentence true in exactly the fields of characteristic $p$, try $1+\dots + 1 = 0$. :0)

Comment: @AlexKruckman Dangit, fixed!

Comment: @NoahSchweber What about the sentence: " There does *not* exist a positive prime number $\;p\;$ such that if $\;1\;$ is the field's multiplicative unit, then $\;p\cdot1=0\;$" . I think this sentence is true in any field of characteristic zero but false in any field of positive characteristic.

Comment: @DonAntonio That's not first-order.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks, though I'm not really that sure about that...anyway, why would it have to be?

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm not certain, but I strongly suspect the OP is interested in first-order statements for a variety of reasons: the tags, the use of the word "sentence" as opposed to property, and the fact that this is a standard exercise in introductory model theory classes. As to why it's not first-order, quantifying over primes isn't something you can do in the language of fields. Even in $\mathbb{R}$, the set of primes in the usual sense is undefinable since $\mathbb{R}$ is o-minimal; and the primes don't even exist in most fields. That quantification is not first-order, then.

Comment: Each *specific* statement of the form "the characteristic is not $p$" can be expressed as a first-order sentence, of length roughly $2p$. From this, we *can* write that sentence as an *infinitary first-order* sentence - the conjunction of "the characteristic is not $p$" for $p$ prime. However, that's a very different thing.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: even if it was definable, it would not be the set of prime numbers (for most models).